# (CSS) How position text (with background color) over <img> tag without absolute positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, hover, positioning

As the title says

my code is something like this :

```
<div class=container> <img/> <div>some text with line one, line two , line three </div> </div>
```

the container should have overflow:hidden and my text would be in more than one line , so I need only a small part of my text to appear at the bottom of container, so when user hovers, the full text appears.

I want to position text over img WITHOUT absolute positioning.
I tried negative margins, but text wouldn't have BG color there.
Also tried Relative pos. => works great but not on chance on IE.

here is an image of what I want
[image]

Comment: Shall we bring you a unicorn as well?

Comment: I think that `position: absolute;` is the only way to get this. Is there a reason you don't want to use it?

Comment: @Ender : Just two please :)
@David-Thomas : Every thing goes crazy in IE6 when make it absolute, and I don't have enough expert to deal with it (do u have suggestions for that issue ??)

Comment: Dude, please don't support ie6 for the love of god. unless it's for your business or something you really shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Bialy: [Are you sure you care about IE6?](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) Is there a solid reason you're supporting it?

Comment: @Bialy: Also, you can't just add IE6 support as an *afterthought* to your question. Supporting IE6 is a massive pain, and completely changes the answers people can give. You should've tagged your question `internet-explorer-6` and wrote it in your question.

Comment: OOOOOKey guys, I already hate that browser, but I'm from EGYPT and most internet users here just use IE pre-installed on windows.
THEY REPRESENT A LARGE SCALE OF INTERNET USERS HERE ! and I don't want to loose any users from my site.
THANKS for the comments people :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason not to use `position: absolute`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/NeaR4/

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    border: 2px dashed #444;
    float: left;
    position: relative
}
.container img {
    display: block
}
.container > div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 14px;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: bold 14px Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px;
}
.container:hover > div {
    height: auto
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/230x180/f0f/fff" />
    <div>some text with line oneeee, line twoooooooo ooooooo , line three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already use absolute positioning and was looking for something better , anyhow THANKS for your time :)

Comment: I'll have a look at getting that working in IE6. Are you alright with using (minor) JavaScript?

Comment: *(after I noticed you accepted my answer that doesn't work in IE6)* Should I look at making this work in IE6?

Comment: If you have some time , I would like to see any js solution specific for that browser :(

Comment: @Bialy: Here's a version that mostly works in IE6, using jQuery where necessary: [http://fiddle.jshell.net/euawG/show/light/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/euawG/show/light/) / [http://jsfiddle.net/euawG/](http://jsfiddle.net/euawG/) - note that I'm using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) to run the code (as opposed to `.ready()`).

Answer (score 2):

`position:relative` solves your problem

Comment: Relative did for me. Bugged me for some time now. Kinda weird the solution was lack of relative. Thanks.