# IE7/Quirks Mode Child Div Hover Problem

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, hover, html-table

Effect:

A hovering box with text and a button that appears when you hover over the TD element.  In IE 7 the box will appear but disappears as soon as you try to hover over it.  IE8+/FF/Ch/Sf all allow you to hover over the child DIV fine.  What am I doing wrong?

Simple code:

CSS

```
td {
    position:relative;
    width:30px;
}

.hovering_box { 
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:25px;
}

td .slot:hover .hovering_box {
    display:block;
}

.hovering_box:hover {
    display:block;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class='slot'>
        <div class='hovering_box'>
          <span class='box_title'>Title Here</span>
          <span class='box_message'>Help me!</span>
          <button>OK!</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if your example is real helpful: http://jsfiddle.net/Ew9GU/ (it doesn't show anything to hover over...)

Comment: Sorry-I tried to simplify it, obviously I missed something. This is a better demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ew9GU/8/

Comment: Please look at this: http://tinypic.com/r/4i0tg9/7 - I added color to the TD next to it, and the div shows up underneath the div...this is in IE7 mode.  I noticed when adding another column cell next to the div, when the mouse enters the next TD the div disappears.  The link above illustrates the effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE6 doesn't support hover on elements other then links, so you will have to use javascript to support IE6. I would advise just using some jQuery to kick IE6 and IE7 into compatibility.

```
$('td .slot').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Then modify your css like so.

```
td .slot:hover .hovering_box,td .slot.hover .hovering_box {
    display:block;
}

.hovering_box:hover,.hovering_box.hover {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I shouldn't have put IE6 in there, sorry :) This is an IE7 problem, and since it supports the hover function already I'd prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: @Psyborg: Your ["better demo" jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ew9GU/8/) already works in IE7. However, it won't work if IE7 is in Quirks Mode. If that's the case, then either @Lime's jQuery fix, or Whatever:hover from my answer will fix it.

Comment: Thanks.  I never should've trusted IE developer tools to render IE7 content.

Comment: it can't be quirks mode, as, in quirks mode, the box doesn't appear at all due to the "hover" thing @Psyborg say's in question the box actually appears but then disappears when the you try to hover over the box itself..(I presume to click the buttons?) - like @thirtydot I get the sample to work in IE7, I think perhaps there's some code not here ( background change perhaps?) that may actually be triggering a haslayout error

Answer (score 2):

As @Lime correctly stated, IE6 doesn't support `:hover` on elements other than `a`.

To remedy this, I recommend that you use [Whatever:hover](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/csshover.html):

> Whatever:hover is a small script that
>   automatically patches `:hover`, `:active`
>   and `:focus` for IE6, IE7 and IE8
>   quirks, letting you use them like you
>   would in any other browser.

I think that this is a cleaner and easier option than rolling your own `:hover` emulation.

Comment: +1 Yeah this is a great option, but I think it varies on a per user basis.  For example, If he is already using jQuery then it could present additional overhead.  Also the headers can get tricky will linking to filse like this.  Overall great idea

Comment: @Lime: The jQuery fix is a valid option (I've used it [myself before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998676/5998791#5998791) [check the comments]), and you already have +1 from me :) But, consider: this fix is inserted via CSS with `behavior: url("csshover3.htc")`, so only IE will download it - and it will be (..or should be) cached, so it only has to be downloaded once. It *automatically* fixes all instances of `:hover`, instead of you having to go around and *manually* patch *each instance* of `:hover` with extra JavaScript *and* extra CSS.

Comment: Yeah also behaviors are relative to the current document, which is well kinda weird.  What was MS thinking?!?  Overall both will work ;)

Comment: whatever:hover, wonderful as it is, can actally be superceded with a direct behaviour on a single rule - why call the behaviour for all elements when the behaviour can be narrowed even further - and via CSS which is still cached! ;)