# how to display text background-color in the picture

Tags: html, css

I would like to display the background-color of the text in the picture **without changing the position.** How can I do that?

```
<div id="pic" ><img src="c.jpg" width="200" height="200"></div>
<p id="text"> ABC</p>

<style>
    #text {
        background-color:#ff0000;
        margin-top: -50px;
        position: static;

    }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: WITHOUT CHANGING THE POSITION.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an ordering issue, the picture is above the background color, the text is above the picture.

See this answer for ways this was accomplished:
[(CSS) How position text (with background color) over <img> tag without absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998676/css-how-position-text-with-background-color-over-img-tag-without-absolute)

Answer (score 0):

Change `position: static` to `position: relative`

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: relative;` instead of `position: static;`

Answer (score 0):

Just change from static to relative.

```
<style>
    #text {
        background-color:#ff0000;
        margin-top: -50px;
        position: relative;
    }
</style>
```

And if you want to be doubly sure, `z-index: 1;`

Comment: I know that it will work if I change the position, but it will mess everything up. It has to be static. I tried z-index and it doesn't work with position: static.

Comment: Can I ask how it messes everything up? We may find a workaround that allows you to use `position: relative` depending on the situation. What is currently depending on that being static?

Comment: If you can change the position and  z-index of the img then that could work for you. `img{ position: relative; z-index: -1; }`

Comment: it gets complicated, if I use other position, there will be gaps in between pictures which I don't want, and because I designed the text to fade out when hover, the pictures will move around when the text is fading out and fading in. And it must adjust depending on browser size, the problem goes on and on. Relative will work, but there will be gap between pictures.

Comment: I found the issue. Your `li:after` needs the style `content: '';`  If you want your labels to be aligned to the vertical centre of the boxes, change their margin to `0 5px` and add a margin to the li instead to spread the lines out.